# Run clickhouse-client and clickhouse-local on a Alpine docker container

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, clickhouse

I have this app that uses clickhouse-client to connect on an external clickhouse-server installation.

Everything goes fine when running this app at a docker alpine container, except the clickhouse-client library.

I have tried to pre-built packages, but I had no success. Is there some way to have this clickhouse-client (not the server) enable on an Alpine Docker Container?

Comment: could you clarify your question - in the title defined 'clickhouse-local' - you cannot dockerize *clickhouse-local*? Could you provide your code & more details about error/exception, etc.

Comment: Is there some `apk add clickhouse-client` to docker alpine images? I have tried, but I hade no success.